# Send email using Html and javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

```
<form action="mailto:you@yourdmainhere.com" method="post" enctype="text/plain" >
FirstName:<input type="text" name="FirstName">
Email:<input type="text" name="Email">
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

I want to send email without using server side language,is it possible to send email using html and java script?

Comment: Just to clearify: Do you want to automatically send a predefined or generated email with html and javascript?

Comment: No i don't want to automatically send a predefined or generated email

Comment: impossible is nothing.I think there is a way to send email without using server side language

Comment: That would be a huge security risk if you could.

Comment: You *could* write an SMTP client in JavaScript; see [email.js](http://emailjs.org).

Answer (score 2):

You can trigger the users default mailer like Billy said. You can also pre-populate the fields like this:

```
<a href="mailto:me@me.com?subject=Your+tip+on+mailto+links&body=Thanks+for+this+tip">Mail me</a>
```

Note that to actually send the email, that is <s>simply not possible</s> impractical with client side JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

Some combinations of browsers and mail clients support [mailto forms](http://www.techrepublic.com/article/set-up-an-html-mailto-form-without-a-back-end-script/).

Submitting the form will (hopefully) open a pre-filled mail in the user's mail client, but not send it.

Example code from the linked-to page:

```
<form action="mailto:admin@example.com" enctype="text/plain" method="post">
<p>Name: <input name="Name" type="text" id="Name" size="40"></p>
<p>E-mail address: <input name="E-mail" type="text" id="E-mail" size="40"></p>
<p>Comment:</p>
<p><textarea name="Comment" cols="55" rows="5"
id="Comment"></textarea></p>
<p><input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Submit"></p>
</form>
```

The page also has a form to try out.

Comment: Above code uses outLook express.I don't want to use Outlook express,is there any alternative method?

Comment: It uses whatever mail client the user has.

Answer (score 0):

Another possible solution is to use an external service. For example [FormKeep](https://formkeep.com/) can save data for you. It seems it can even use webhooks to trigger email.

I'm sure there are many other similar services out there to be found, depending on your needs. [Googling "form email service"](https://www.google.com/search?q=form+email+service) seems to turn up several.

Answer (score 0):

Without any backend stuff your option is using a mailto in an href.

```
"mailto:"+emailTo+"&subject="+subjectText+"&body="+bodyText
```

You can use, for example, a form with action mailto to let the user change contents. The recommended way is to use a server side language.

On the other hand, as you are asking for javascript, of course you can send emails with nodejs, but this is server side javascript ( but javascript ). http://www.nodemailer.com

Answer (score -1):

```
<a href="mailto:me@me.com">Mail me</a>
```

Note that this is open to spammers grabbing the email address, this opens the users computers default mailer